# Is there a way to create relations between different connections in Typerom entity?

Tags: database, typescript, backend, typeorm

I create 2 connections using TypeORM as followed:

```
await createConnections([
    {
      name: "conn1",
      type: "mssql",
      host: "localhost",
      port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT || "1433"),
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      logging: true,
      entities: [__dirname + "/entities/example/*{.js,.ts}"],
      options: {
        enableArithAbort: true,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "conn2",
      type: "mssql",
      host: "localhost",
      port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT || "1433"),
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME1,
      logging: true,
      entities: [__dirname + "/entities/*{.js,.ts}"],
      options: {
        enableArithAbort: true,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

My Employee Entity is in conn1, User Entity is in conn2. Then I setup OneToOne between Employee and User like:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity("Employees")
export class Employee extends BaseEntity {
  ...
  @Field(() => User, { nullable: true })
  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.employee)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "EmployeeID", referencedColumnName: "id" })
  user: User | null = null;
}

@ObjectType()
@Entity({ name: "User" })
export class GMGUser extends BaseEntity {
...
  @Field(() => Employee)
  @OneToOne(() => Employee, (employee) => employee.user)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "id", referencedColumnName: "EmployeeID" })
  employee!: Employee;
}
```

But I still got an Error: Entity metadata for User#employee was not found or Employee#user not found after I check all connections; import path and spells are correct. I try setup relations in each of the connections are also working. But I cannot figure out how to set up relations between different connections in TypeORM. Welcome any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: is.it.working when both entities are in the same connection?

Comment: I tried to put all entities in one connection which seems alright because the error is not shown. but I got null through the OneToOne relationship. All relations are working in each connection, but not working between the 2 connections. I am looking a way to create the relation between the 2 different connections.

Comment: I would suggest to activate the logs in both connections and send the query that is executed. As far as I'm I do not use "joinColumn"  when definjnh the relations. Also I dont not set the entities path in the connection definition, but rather create an array of entities, that I sent in the createConnection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The reason why I use "joinColumn" is I create relationship on exsiting tables where the names do not match the default typeorm column name. By using joinColumn, I can specify the column name.